# How to use a Select Query with inner joins without having repeated rows?

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clientes](
    [IdCliente] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ApellidoPaterno] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ApellidoMaterno] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Empresa] [text] NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Clientes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatosLegales](
    [IdDatoLegal] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdCliente] [int] NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RFC] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DatosLegales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Facturas](
    [IdFactura] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdCliente] [int] NULL,
    [IdDatoLegal] [int] NULL,
    [Serie] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Folio] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [UUID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FechaEmision] [date] NULL,
    [HoraEmision] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [RutaXML] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RutaCBB] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RutaPDF] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Facturas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

Foreign Keys on
Clientes.IdCliente = DatosLegales.IdCliente
DatosLegales.IdDatoLegal = Facturas.IdDatoLegal

I am using the following query

```
SELECT Facturas.IdFactura, Facturas.IdGrupo, (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre) AS Cliente, DatosLegales.Nombre, Facturas.Serie, Facturas.Folio, Facturas.UUID, Facturas.Estado, Facturas.FechaEmision, Facturas.HoraEmision 
FROM Facturas 
INNER JOIN Ventas ON (Facturas.IdFactura = Ventas.IdFactura) 
INNER JOIN Clientes ON (Clientes.IdCliente = Ventas.IdCliente) 
INNER JOIN DatosLegales ON (DatosLegales.IdDatoLegal = Facturas.IdDatoLegal) 
WHERE Facturas.IdGrupo = 1 AND (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre LIKE '%55%' OR  Clientes.Nombre + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno LIKE '%55%' OR DatosLegales.Nombre LIKE '%55%' OR Facturas.Serie LIKE '%55%' OR Facturas.Folio LIKE '%55%' OR Facturas.UUID LIKE '%55%' OR Facturas.IdFactura LIKE '%55%') 
ORDER BY IdFactura DESC
```

And I am getting one specific row at least three times...
I think that is because (since I use Like%55%) for every match on 55 it will show that row.
However I only need to display those rows once.
What can I do to fix that issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  The number of matches in the `where` clause has nothing to do with duplicates.

The duplicates are created because there are duplicates in one or more of the tables used for joining.  If you are getting full duplicates (all columns), you can do:

```
select distinct . . .
```

The `distinct` keyword removes row duplicates.

I encourage you to find the root of the problem.  Distinct is a relatively expensive operation.  In this context, it would be used as a bandage to hide the actual problem -- which is duplicates in the underlying tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Facturas.IdFactura,
     Facturas.IdGrupo,
     (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre)
         AS Cliente,
     DatosLegales.Nombre,
     Facturas.Serie,
     Facturas.Folio,
     Facturas.UUID,
     Facturas.Estado,
     Facturas.FechaEmision,
     Facturas.HoraEmision
FROM Facturas
     INNER JOIN Ventas
         ON (Facturas.IdFactura = Ventas.IdFactura)
     INNER JOIN Clientes
         ON (Clientes.IdCliente = Ventas.IdCliente)
     INNER JOIN DatosLegales
         ON (DatosLegales.IdDatoLegal = Facturas.IdDatoLegal) WHERE Facturas.IdGrupo = 1
     AND (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre LIKE
              '%55%'
          OR Clientes.Nombre + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno LIKE
                 '%55%'
          OR DatosLegales.Nombre LIKE '%55%'
          OR Facturas.Serie LIKE '%55%'
          OR Facturas.Folio LIKE '%55%'
          OR Facturas.UUID LIKE '%55%'
          OR Facturas.IdFactura LIKE '%55%') ORDER BY IdFactura DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Facturas.IdFactura,
         Facturas.IdGrupo,
         (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre)
             AS Cliente,
         DatosLegales.Nombre,
         Facturas.Serie,
         Facturas.Folio,
         Facturas.UUID,
         Facturas.Estado,
         Facturas.FechaEmision,
         Facturas.HoraEmision
    FROM Facturas
         INNER JOIN Clientes
             ON (Clientes.IdCliente = Facturas.IdCliente)
         INNER JOIN DatosLegales
             ON (DatosLegales.IdDatoLegal = Facturas.IdDatoLegal)
   WHERE Facturas.IdGrupo = 1
         AND (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre LIKE
                  '%55%'
              OR DatosLegales.Nombre LIKE '%55%'
              OR Facturas.Serie LIKE '%55%'
              OR Facturas.Folio LIKE '%55%'
              OR Facturas.UUID LIKE '%55%'
              OR Facturas.IdFactura LIKE '%55%')
ORDER BY IdFactura DESC;
```

Removed the following check because since you are using the LIKE clause, you not need it twice

```
OR Clientes.Nombre + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno LIKE
                     '%55%'
```

I also removed the following JOIN and fixed the JOIN between Facturas and Client since you have the Id in obth tables.:

```
INNER JOIN Ventas
             ON (Facturas.IdFactura = Ventas.IdFactura)
```

IF `DatosLegales.Nombre` is the same field as `Clientes.Nombre` remove also it.

Not sure if both things will solve your problem but at least improves your query.